# mongoDB mapReduce: reduce function returning plain object instead of map

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

Is it possible to have a reduce function that returns a flat object instead of map-like thing?

More details:

```
db.getCollection('calls').mapReduce(function () {
    emit(this.reportDate + '-' + this.reportTime, {
        from: this.caller,
        to: this.called,
        callEnds: this.callEnds,
        callBegins: this.callBegins,
        location: this.location
    });
}, function (k, v) {
    var result = {};
    v.forEach(function (value) {
        result.from = value.from;
        result.to = value.to;
        result.callBegins = value.callBegins;
        result.callEnds = value.callEnds;
        if (value.location) {
            result.location = value.location;
        }
    });
    return result;
}, {
   out: 'mapReducedCalls'
})
```

Using this, output collection's documents are all

```
{ "_id" : "k",
  "value" : 
{ "from" : "b5c06aafa4be00db3d6acadb67b6ceef",
    "to" : "0afba72b041e3ccb5a62f0b0b44cceea",
    "callEnds" : "01/03/2013 10:45:44",
    "callBegins" : "01/03/2013 10:45:40",
    "location" : 44763
} 
}
```

While I'd rather have it in a flat object form like

```
{ "_id" : "k",
  "from" : "b5c06aafa4be00db3d6acadb67b6ceef",
  "to" : "0afba72b041e3ccb5a62f0b0b44cceea",
  "callEnds" : "01/03/2013 10:45:44",
  "callBegins" : "01/03/2013 10:45:40",
  "location" : 44763
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the 'value' field is currently required (assuming that's what you mean by map-like thing).